# Print all elements in PHP array HTML view

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project, which describe in simplest form with following tables

## tbl_direct_fuel table

```
+----------------+------------+------------+
| direct_fuel_id | vehicle_id | issue_date |
+----------------+------------+------------+
|              1 |       1000 | 2019-10-01 |
|              2 |       1001 | 2019-10-02 |
+----------------+------------+------------+
```

## tbl_direct_fuel_details table

```
+-----------------------+----------------+---------+----------+
| direct_fuel_detail_id | direct_fuel_id | item_id | fuel_qty |
+-----------------------+----------------+---------+----------+
|                   100 |              1 |      50 |     1.00 |
|                   101 |              2 |      60 |     2.00 |
+-----------------------+----------------+---------+----------+
```

## store_item table

```
+---------+-----------+
| item_id | item_name |
+---------+-----------+
|      50 | DOT 3     |
|      60 | DOT 4     |
|      70 | DOT 5     |
+---------+-----------+
```

I tried to print fuel_qty in numbers & also in words as follows using my view

```
1.00    One and Cents Zero Only
2.00    Two and Cents Zero Only
```

## Model

```
public function directFuelQtyById($id) {

        $this->db->select('tbl_direct_fuel_details.fuel_qty');
        $this->db->from('tbl_direct_fuel_details');
        $this->db->join('tbl_direct_fuel', 'tbl_direct_fuel_details.direct_fuel_id=tbl_direct_fuel.direct_fuel_id', 'inner');

        $this->db->where('tbl_direct_fuel.status=1 and tbl_direct_fuel.direct_fuel_id="'.$id.'"');
        $this->db->order_by('tbl_direct_fuel.direct_fuel_id','DESC');
        $q = $this->db->get();

        if ($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $q->result();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

## Controller

```
public function convert_number_to_words($number)
    {

        $hyphen = ' ';
        $conjunction = ' and ';
        $separator = ' ';
        $negative = 'negative ';
        $decimal = ' and Cents ';
        $dictionary = array(
            0 => 'Zero',
            1 => 'One',
            2 => 'Two',
            3 => 'Three',
            4 => 'Four',
            5 => 'Five',
            6 => 'Six',
            7 => 'Seven',
            8 => 'Eight',
            9 => 'Nine',
            10 => 'Ten',
            11 => 'Eleven',
            12 => 'Twelve',
            13 => 'Thirteen',
            14 => 'Fourteen',
            15 => 'Fifteen',
            16 => 'Sixteen',
            17 => 'Seventeen',
            18 => 'Eighteen',
            19 => 'Nineteen',
            20 => 'Twenty',
            30 => 'Thirty',
            40 => 'Fourty',
            50 => 'Fifty',
            60 => 'Sixty',
            70 => 'Seventy',
            80 => 'Eighty',
            90 => 'Ninety',
            100 => 'Hundred',
            1000 => 'Thousand',
            1000000 => 'Million',
        );

        if (!is_numeric($number)) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($number < 0) {
            return $negative . $this->convert_number_to_words(abs($number));
        }

        $string = $fraction = null;

        if (strpos($number, '.') !== false) {
            list($number, $fraction) = explode('.', $number);
        }

        switch (true) {
            case $number < 21:
                $string = $dictionary[$number];
                break;
            case $number < 100:
                $tens = ((int)($number / 10)) * 10;
                $units = $number % 10;
                $string = $dictionary[$tens];
                if ($units) {
                    $string .= $hyphen . $dictionary[$units];
                }
                break;
            case $number < 1000:
                $hundreds = $number / 100;
                $remainder = $number % 100;
                $string = $dictionary[$hundreds] . ' ' . $dictionary[100];
                if ($remainder) {
                    $string .= $conjunction . $this->convert_number_to_words($remainder);
                }
                break;
            default:
                $baseUnit = pow(1000, floor(log($number, 1000)));
                $numBaseUnits = (int)($number / $baseUnit);
                $remainder = $number % $baseUnit;
                $string = $this->convert_number_to_words($numBaseUnits) . ' ' . $dictionary[$baseUnit];
                if ($remainder) {
                    $string .= $remainder < 100 ? $conjunction : $separator;
                    $string .= $this->convert_number_to_words($remainder);
                }
                break;
        }

        if (null !== $fraction && is_numeric($fraction)) {
            $string .= $decimal;
            $words = array();
            foreach (str_split((string)$fraction) as $number) {
                $words[] = $dictionary[$number];
            }
            $string .= implode(' ', $words);
        }

        return $string;
    }
    /////////////////////

    public function printFuel($id){

        $this->data['printData']=$this->Fuel_model->directFuelById($id);        
        $fuel = $this->Fuel_model->directFuelQtyById($id);      
        foreach($fuel as $obj)
    { 
    $this->amount_word = $this->convert_number_to_words($obj->fuel_qty) . '<br>'." Only"; 
    }

        $this->load->view('/template/directFuel/printFuel',  $this->data);

    }
```

## View (printFuel)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Fuel Order</title>
</head>
<body onload="window.print()">
<body>

<div class="col-xs-12 table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered"  style="font-size: 13px; ">
<tbody>
<?php
if (!empty($printData)) {
  $offset=1; // cm
  $cnt=0;
  foreach ($printData as $item) {
?>
<tr>        

  <td><p style="position: absolute;top: <?= ($cnt*$offset)+20 ?>cm;right: 12cm"><?=$item->fuel_qty?> Litres</p></td>
  <td><p style="position: absolute;top: <?= ($cnt*$offset)+20 ?>cm;right: 8cm"><?=$this->amount_word?></p></td>                           
</tr> 
<?php $cnt++; 
  } // close your foreach HERE
  ?>         
</tbody>
</table>
</div>

<?php   
}    
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But when converting to words, the function prints only the last element for `<?=$this->amount_word?>`,  like below:

```
1.00    Two and Cents Zero Only
2.00    Two and Cents Zero Only
```

How to get the desired output?

```
1.00    One and Cents Zero Only
2.00    Two and Cents Zero Only
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `printFuel($id)` you are overwriting `$this->amount_word` with each new array value. Therefore you only get the very last value.

So just convert each amount  you get in `$item->fuel_qty` into a text string `$item->fuel_qty_str` using the function `convert_number_to_words()` in your controller:

```
public function printFuel($id){
    $arr=$this->Fuel_model->directFuelById($id);               
    foreach($arr as $key=>$obj)
    { 
       $str=$this->convert_number_to_words($obj->fuel_qty) . '<br>'." Only";
       $arr[$key]->fuel_qty_str=$str;    
    }
    $data['printData']=$arr;
    $this->load->view('/template/directFuel/printFuel',  $data);

}
```

and then output the array in your view:

```
foreach ($printData as $item) {
  ?>
  <tr>          
    <td>
      <p style="position: absolute;top: <?= ($cnt*$offset)+20 ?>cm;right: 12cm">
        <?=$item->fuel_qty?> Litres
      </p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p style="position: absolute;top: <?= ($cnt*$offset)+20 ?>cm;right: 8cm">
        <?=$item->fuel_qty_str?>
      </p>
    </td>                           
  </tr> 
  <?php $cnt++; 
}
```